# Android - How to get future time value

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I add n hours to past time in millis? I found another example using days on StackOverflow, but still don't understand how to do it with hours.

Answer (score 2):

```
val timeWithAddedHours = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
     time = Date(timeMillis) //replace timeMillis with past time in millis you want to set like 1604938191509..In case you want to set current time then remove this parameter like Date() 
     add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1)
}.time 

println(timeWithAddedHours)
```